# Twilio clean up connection - websocket "Close received after close"

Tags: twilio

I'm using Twilio to make calls from my system. I'm using v 1.4 of JS client SDK.

When I want to clean up connection to Twilio when closing the "Dialer Page" I close (finish) all connections and then call:

```
Twilio.Device.destroy();
```

And then I receive an error on console which is probably strictly related with SDK itself:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://chunderw-vpc-gll.twilio.com/signal' failed: Close received after close
```

I cannot find anything in official documentation so maybe there is a proper way to do the clean up?

Maybe I should call "destroy" after Device change status to "offline"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i have same issue, has anyone solved this?

Comment: Hey I know it has been a while but did you solve this by any chance?

Comment: Bumping up version to 1.5 and follow instruction to migrate to this version resolves the problem for me.

Comment: I'm still having the same problem, did anyone find a fix for it?